# How to store response retrofit data into list

Tags: android, list, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm working with retrofit in mobile android, I want to store response data into my public List, I have been try but my List still null but data can show in onResponse

this is my retrofit

```java
 private APIInterface getInterfaceService() {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
        final APIInterface mInterfaceService = retrofit.create(APIInterface.class);
        return mInterfaceService;
    }

    private void trendingQuestion(final List<Trending> listTrending){
        progressDialog.show();
        APIInterface mApiService = this.getInterfaceService();
        Call<ResponseTrendsQuestion> mService = mApiService.getTendingQuestion();
        mService.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseTrendsQuestion>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseTrendsQuestion> call, Response<ResponseTrendsQuestion> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    for(int i=0;i<response.body().getData().size();i++) {
                        listTrending.add(new Trending(Integer.valueOf(response.body().getData().get(i).getId()),response.body().getData().get(i).getTitle(),
                                response.body().getData().get(i).getDescription(),
                                Integer.valueOf(response.body().getData().get(i).getLikes()),
                                Integer.valueOf(response.body().getData().get(i).getDislikes()),
                                Integer.valueOf(response.body().getData().get(i).getComment())));
                        Log.d("message",response.body().getData().get(i).getId());
                    }
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }else{
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Log.d("message",response.errorBody().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), response.errorBody().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseTrendsQuestion> call, Throwable t) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Connection Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

my list

```java
listTrending = new ArrayList<>();
        trendingQuestion(listTrending);
```

Comment: Can you share what your response, and `Trending` object look like? Also, it looks like you are using `gson`, so you shouldn't need to parse out your response, `gson` does it for you if it's implemented properly.

Comment: I think gson parsing is failing and hence your list is null. Do you expect `List<ResponseTrendsQuestion>` in response or `ResponseTrendsQuestion`?

Comment: Add logs there suppose to be an error message like error of deserialization or something like that

Comment: Can you post your JSON Response as well.

Answer (score 0):

1) Problem is that you call response.body() multiple times, while it returns body only once.

1st call here returns body:

```
for(int i=0;i<response.body().getData().size();i++) {
```

All others calls return empty body. There is no data to add to your list, since you lose it on a first call. Save body to variable before cycle and use it instead.

2) Suppose it makes sense to use [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) instead since ArrayList is not thread safe (suppose depending on your use case you can attempt to modify it concurrently).